# SQLite query result is missing first row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I need to check a timestamp in an SQLite database table against a timestamp I have as a variable.  When I run a select statement against my table I appear to be missing the first record.

```
lastMod = dict[@"LastMod"];
[self openDB];
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT LastMod FROM %@ order by Lastmod desc", newTableName];

const char *sqlQueryChars = [sqlQuery cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

sqlite3_stmt *statementChk;

sqlite3_prepare_v2(congressDB, sqlQueryChars, -1, &statementChk, NULL);

if (sqlite3_step(statementChk) == SQLITE_ERROR){

    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(congressDB));
    sqlite3_close(congressDB);

} else {

    if (sqlite3_step(statementChk) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statementChk, 0)];
        NSNumberFormatter *resultNumberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [resultNumberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        NSNumber *resultNumber = [resultNumberFormatter numberFromString:resultString];

        if (resultNumber){

            if ([lastMod integerValue] > [resultNumber integerValue]) {

                needsUpdating = @"YES";

            } else {

                needsUpdating = @"NO";

            }

        }

    } else {

        needsUpdating = @"YES";  // No rows found, table is empty and needs filling

}
```

The newest records in the database are:

```
1390393860
1390385996
1390385681
...
```

The one I want and am expecting is the top one - 1390393860, the biggest number (which is the newest record).  But I am getting the second one 1390385996.  If I change the query to:

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT LastMod FROM %@ order by Lastmod desc limit 1", newTableName];
```

The program says no rows were returned.  Testing this query directly on the database returns the correct row.  What's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cos you call `sqlite_step()` twice:

```
if (sqlite3_step(statementChk) == SQLITE_ERROR){

    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(congressDB));
    sqlite3_close(congressDB);

} else {

    if (sqlite3_step(statementChk) == SQLITE_ROW) {
```

When you should be using the last call only:

```
if (sqlite3_step(statementChk) == SQLITE_ROW) {
```

(you want to fetch the next row and react only if there is an error).

Comment: This is exactly what the problem is, a silly mistake by me.  Thanks for your help, much appreciated!